# Which public key format should be used for libssh2 public key authentication?

Tags: ssh, networking, key-authentication

I am trying pass publickey (id_rsa.pub) for sftp_write example in libssh2 library.

```
const char *pubkey = "/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub";
const char *privkey = NULL;

if(libssh2_userauth_publickey_fromfile(session, username,

                                       pubkey, privkey,
                                       password)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\tAuthentication by public key failed\n");
    goto shutdown;
}
```

I have tried openssh format and standard ssh format keys as below.

I got the below errors  for two formats of the

- standard ssh format, `Athentication failed: cannot open the file -16`

  ```
  ---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
  AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCjnPF5vKg7NuUXkGbK0Nh5d3GjLNXHB+VozgVn5Ego
  DVSjwezr30YJm8gzGrk5aUAEJKbWSUczVj9vCrn7O54K1/VXOggC1a6pun3+Iqvuv0BINRj3
  YuC+c9s803mYPSpzZpNPFf3Uj49lKrroUIdnEz3qo/Z9kFbpWfClJPlb7xjrZaZkSgolbxih
  8gZ0w3iAuMR5nwnEGQnHkk751jxOtYopzT4w31gFmFYcq/LRbP4S2xJ0r8wl58J8Mm/U/yZx
  EhDARHx/mkqMILofAqFvsFSaaASUuFmB9uUJsgJ69s9FbgXnpGhyGoH0nyVsdM/oqwIXtJji
  IvbVBEomnCrX
  ---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
  ```
- Open SSH Format, Authentication failed

  ```
     LIBSSH2_ERROR_PUBLICKEY_UNRECOGNIZED \ 
     LIBSSH2_ERROR_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED ,-18
  ```

  ```
  "ssh-rsa" AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCjnPF5vKg7NuUXkGbK0Nh5d3GjLNXHB+VozgVn5EgoDVSjwezr30YJm8gzGrk5aUAEJKbWSUczVj9vCrn7O54K1/VXOggC1a6pun3+Iqvuv0BINRj3YuC+c9s803mYPSpzZpNPFf3Uj49lKrroUIdnEz3qo/Z9kFbpWfClJPlb7xjrZaZkSgolbxih8gZ0w3iAuMR5nwnEGQnHkk751jxOtYopzT4w31gFmFYcq/LRbP4S2xJ0r8wl58J8Mm/U/yZxEhDARHx/mkqMILofAqFvsFSaaASUuFmB9uUJsgJ69s9FbgXnpGhyGoH0nyVsdM/oqwIXtJjiIvbVBEomnCrX
  ```

Can some one suggest if its the public key format problem.

I am using Bitvise server on windows  for testing the libssh2 client publickey authentication.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not passing the private key to libssh2.

SSH pubkey authentication requires two machines, a server and client. The client should generate a private and public keypair, where the public key should be copied to the server using any method available prior to pubkey authentication attempts.The private key should never leave the client.

When connecting to the server using the client, one should use the private key. Authenticating using only the public key only will not work, as you can only encrypt the negotiation packets, but never actually decrypt them. Reading through the [documentation](https://www.libssh2.org/libssh2_userauth_publickey_fromfile_ex.html) also states that the private key is a must, while the public key might be set to NULL in some cases.

### Reproducing the problem

I've tried reproducing the error, but it seems to work for me, below I will describe how I did it, and some speculations regarding your problem:

1. Made a directory and copied in the example file `sftp_write.c` from [libssh2](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/master/example/sftp_write.c).
2. Changed `auth_pw` from `1` to `0` on line 27.
3. Changed pubkey and privkey to use my own keys, and added debugging.

```c
    const char *pubkey = "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_PEM.pub";
    const char *privkey = "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_PEM";
    int liberr;
    if(liberr = libssh2_userauth_publickey_fromfile(session, username,
                                               pubkey, privkey,
                                               password)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\tAuthentication by public key failed: %d\n", liberr);
        goto shutdown;
    }
```

4. changed

```c
#include "libssh2_config.h"
#include <libssh2.h>
#include <libssh2_sftp.h>

#ifdef HAVE_WINSOCK2_H
# include <winsock2.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H
# include <sys/socket.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_NETINET_IN_H
# include <netinet/in.h>
#endif
# ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_ARPA_INET_H
# include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif
```

to

```c
#include <libssh2.h>
#include <libssh2_sftp.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

To match my setup.

5. Used Docker to compile the image by running

```bash
docker run -i --rm \
    -w $(pwd) -v $(pwd):$(pwd) \
    -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro  \
    -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro \
    -u $(id -u):$(id -u) \
    datafr/libssh2:latest \
    gcc -g -I /usr/include/ -L /usr/lib/ -l ssh2 sftp_write.c -o a.out
```

6. Ran the program with

```bash
./a.out 127.0.0.1 $USER
```

#### Results

Running this code results in error -19: `LIBSSH2_ERROR_PUBLICKEY_UNVERIFIED`. This is because the docker image uses an older version of libssh2 which requires older PEM keys. This is fixed by creating a new keypair with

```bash
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P "" -f id_rsa_PEM
```

And modifying the code to use the new keys.

Running the code once more gives us error -18: `LIBSSH2_ERROR_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED`. This is fixed by adding our new public key `id_rsa_PEM.pub` to the servers `authorized_keys`-file.

After this, we get no more errors, and the output looks like this:

```
$ ./a.out 127.0.0.1 $USER
Fingerprint: XXXXXXX
libssh2_sftp_init()!
libssh2_sftp_open()!
libssh2_sftp_open() is done, now send data!
all done
```

And I can confirm the creation of a file called `/tmp/TEST` containing our code from `sftp_write.c`.

### Further speculations

I've noticed that error -16: `LIBSSH2_ERROR_FILE` occurs when the file is either non-existent or has the wrong permissions, so I'll ask you to double check your file permissions. I'll post my own permissions as reference.

Client `~/.ssh/` directory:

```bash
$ ls -alh
total 28K
drwx------  2 user user 4,0K Sep 28 15:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 32 user user 4,0K Sep 28 15:36 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 2,7K Sep 28 15:36 config
-rw-------  1 user user 2,5K Sep 28 15:36 id_rsa_PEM
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  574 Sep 28 15:36 id_rsa_PEM.pub
-rw-------  1 user user 6,3K Sep 28 15:36 known_hosts
```

Server `~/.ssh/` directory:

```bash
$ ls -alh
total 20K
drwx------  2 user user 4,0K Sep 28 15:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 32 user user 4,0K Sep 28 15:39 ..
-rw-------  1 user user 3,4K Sep 28 15:39 authorized_keys
```

Comment: hi Decclo , Thanks for the reply,

Comment: Did it work, or does the problem persist?

Comment: Hi Decclo,  I added the private key, but result is same. basically userauth_publickey_fromfile()  in usrauth.c  ile in ibssh2 library  just uses the public key  for authentication. If the publci key is not available , it will generate the public key using the private key and passphrase. _libssh2_pub_priv_keyfile() is called to gnerate the private key, this is part of openssl library. Since we compiled libssh2 linking openssl library, _libssh2_pub_priv_keyfile is supposed to be linked. Unfortunately there is some trouble in linking _libssh2_pub_priv_keyfile from the openssl.so in  my project.

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaNeelam I've update the answer with some personal experiences I just made. Please note that both the client and server are Ubuntu machines. I Hope this helps you debug your error.

Comment: Oh yea, setting privkey=NULL results in error -19: LIBSSH2_ERROR_PUBLICKEY_UNVERIFIED, as libssh2 doesn't recognize the "file" as a proper keyfile, for good reasons.

Comment: Wow.. Thanks a lot @Decclo.  The authentication is passed after using both keys. setting private key to NULL is causing -19 error.  I have tested the connection between bitvise lient and server and used the keypair.  The authentication is successful.  I will try with ssh-keygen and update you tomorrow.

Comment: libssh2 needs  to be selected the right private key, perhaps its used for some signature generation to verify with the server..( I am not sure) . When I used the ssh-keygen , the authentication was partially successful only. The error message from the server is  " "Authentication Failed,  The public key doesnt match with any of the public keys associated with the user." Only after i have uploaded  public key to server using bitvise client , my sftp_write was able to pass the authentication. Is it manditory to upload the public key to the server before authentication?

Comment: HI Decclo,  Did you ever try two factor authentication with libssh2. ir. Password + Publickey. only one authentciation passes, either password or publickey authentication , the other fails.

Comment: It is indeed necessary to upload the public key, as the client uses the private key for authentication, but the server needs the public, that's why ssh-keygen generates two keys. ;)
https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/public-key-authentication
Sadly I do not know how to setup TFA.

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaNeelam did you manage to fix the issue, or do you need more help?

Comment: HI @Decclo,  The customer said , he has cetificate with private key. I need to use it to create the public key for authentication. Is it how it how they use in  real world practice?  I am told that sftp client doesnt have access to upload the publickey since the normal client access rights are restricted to upload the publickeys , where as the SFTP server admin has access to upload the and delete the authorised keys. is my undestanding correct?

Comment: That does sound logical. You can extract or recreate the public key if you have the private key, but you cannot recreate the private key using the public key. That is also part of the reason why you should never share your private key.

Comment: If the admins have disabled password login for security reasons, or perhaps hidden/locked your own ssh files away from you, then you will have to ask an admin to add your public key to the authorized keys before you can login. Another possibility might be that SFTP might be jailed, meaning that you can only access specific directories when connecting with SFTP. You might be able to circumvent the jail by connecting with SSH instead of SFTP, but the admin should most definitely be able to authorize your public key.

Comment: OK Decclo. Thank you for the wonderful replies.  I got a clear picture about the flow and real case usage.They are helpful in inch  by inch to finish the project.